# Python if-else - conditional error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, scripting

- i am installing some package based on operating system output.
- I want to introduce try-except block (or any better way) for linux1 & linux2 loops to print the package is missing in OS or other error while install
- 3rd loop (Linux-Others) should just give warning and proceed with rest of package installation even if I have error

.

```
import platform
operating_system=platform.platform()
def package_install():
    listA=['package1','pa9ckage2','package3']
    listB=['package4','package5','package6']
    listC=['package10','package20','package30']

    if 'linux1' in operating_system:
        self._log.info("Linux-A")
        yum_command = yum_command = [
                    YUM_EXECUTABLE,
                    "-y",
                    "install"
                ] + listA
        return self._executor.execute_command(yum_command)
    elif 'linux2' in operating_system:
        self._log.info("Linux-B")
        yum_command = yum_command = [
                    YUM_EXECUTABLE,
                    "-y",
                    "install"
                ] + listB
        return self._executor.execute_command(yum_command)
    else: 
        self._log.info("Linux-Others")
        yum_command = yum_command = [
                    YUM_EXECUTABLE,
                    "-y",
                    "install"
                ] + listC
        return self._executor.execute_command(yum_command)
```

Comment: Terminology: there are no loops here, only `if` statements.

Comment: Question: why do you want to introduce a `try...except`? What problem do you see that you think this will solve?

Comment: You are incorrectly using `return` here. `return` must only be used inside a function that you declare with `def`.

Comment: I missed the function to mention here as its a part of bigger code. Thanks.

I want to stop processing once it finds any package not found while installing but 3rd condition in if-else should continue showing error message but not fail

Comment: So what happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do differently instead?